# How can i add space to openvz to existing container?

Tags: virtualization, openvz

this command adding 50G to existing container or it's create container?

```
vzctl set 111 --diskspace 50G:50G --save
```

Answer (score 0):

your command is setting the soft- and hard- diskspacelimit of the existing container: 111 to 50G.

For creating a container use vzctl create or prlctl create.